The chopped pears are then ______ in cans. => packed or packaged? Does it depend on the container?
packed: to put something into a container so that it can be stored, transported or sold
package: to put something into a box, bag, etc. to be sold or transported
When describing the canning stage in the production of pears as canned fruits, what do people write/say?

The chopped pears are then ______ in cans.

I wonder if I should use packed or packaged here. Their dictionary definitions are so similar (I think a box or a bag is also considered a container) that I think it's possible that the better choice will change if I choose another type of container.
I felt tempted to just use placed or put but then decided that I should know the difference between packed and packaged.

Please quote the dictionary definitions and their source. Then explain what you don't understand about them. I believe, in the food canning industry, it is conventional to say food is packed into the cans. Whilst other food is packaged in in boxes and bags, the packaging.

@PeterJennings Sorry for forgetting that. I just put the definitions up there.

In Britain, we might say 'the chopped pears are then canned', but I believe this wouldn't work, or might be ambiguous, in American English. We might also say that they were tinned. The beans for Heinz are grown in North America, dehydrated, shipped to England, then rehydrated, cooked and canned in a factory in Wigan.

If you're about nuanced differences between similar words, stop using learners dictionaries and move up to a dictionary, or better yet, dictionaries, that native speakers would use. Or maybe not, since the definitions you cite, if they are to be relied on, give you the answer you're seeking.  What does OLD say about the verb store?

What @MichaelHarvey said (the chopped pears are then canned). The problem with packed is it tends to imply neatly arranged / packed tightly together in packages - not really a good fit for can contents that are pourable (being largely liquid).

I read it so many times as a kid, it has been burned into my memory:  "Packed as full as practicable by modern automatic equipment, this package contains the full net weight indicated. Contents may have settled due to shipping and handling."  It used to be printed on the outside of snack boxes -- pretzels, crackers, cheese doodles, whatever.   They were not "neatly arranged" but loose.

Location: Northwestern U.S.

Food items and items that do not require packaging (such as Styrofoam or paper) are packed. The container the items are packed in is irrelevant, be it a can or the box the cans themselves are eventually packed in.

Products that require additional packaging material are packaged. Thus, items placed in a container filled with shipping peanuts, Styrofoam or cardboard inserts, or wadded up paper are packaged.



The chopped pears are then packed into cans. The cans are then packed into cases.

... because no packaging is required to prepare the cans for shipping. However (and this is important...)

The guitar was packaged for shipping.

... sounds funny. It's not wrong, but it would be more common to hear...

The guitar was packed for shipping.

I suspect but can't prove that "packaged" was derived from the good old days when people wrapped objects in paper and tied it up with string before shipping it. Literally, the object was "packaged" meaning it was wrapped in packing or perhaps it was prepared as a package for shipping. However, I could easily be wrong about that.
However...
While it would sound funny in my area to say "the chopped pears are then packaged into cans," no one would misunderstand you. Nevertheless, unless you have an instructor who is specifically expecting you to use the word "packaged," defaulting to "packed" in any random case has a very high likelihood of being colloquially correct.

+1 for packing the cans but -1 for saying that no packaging is required for the cans. Cans are boxed at the production facility and the boxes are transferred to a wholesale distribution center for delivery to supermarkets where they are opened and either the lidless boxes are  placed on the shelves  or the individual cans are moved out of the box and placed individually on the shelves.

@TimR I believe you misunderstood me. I'll correct the answer. As stated there, no additional packaging is necessary. Nobody adds paper or Styrofoam or anything else to a box of cans. Nor to cases filled with reams of paper. On the other hand, coffee pots and monitors tend to come with cardboard or Styrofoam inserts... additional packaging.... In short, I don't consider the primary container to be "packaging" (neither the can, nor the box the cans go in).

I envisioned the cans going directly into wooden cases. Are cardboard boxes called  "cases" out your way?

@TimR By itself the cardboard box is, indeed, called a box. However, once packed with food or other items, it quickly gets referred to as a case. grocery stories and supermarkets once regularly held "case lot sales" where cases of good were sold at cheaper prices. Any of us involved with retail inventory refers to everything as "items" and "cases." Conclusion: it depends on who you're talking to.

If you buy a case of bottled beer in the old-school cardboard box whose lid was in two parts that opened up and out like they were on hinges, and you put all the bottles in an ice chest or the fridge, is what you have now "an empty case of beer" or is that phrase only valid if the case contains empty bottles?

@TimR No one would misunderstand what you said, but the phrase "throw the empty box/packaging away" would be more common. Ah, English. The use of "case" is predictably common only when filled with products or in the process of being filled with products. Now that I think about it, if it was a box full of random stuff, nobody here would call it a case. It needs to be all the same product. Otherwise, it's just a box full of stuff. :-)


The chopped pears are then canned and the cans packed in boxes.

canned is used across all varieties of English.

putting cans in boxes is packing them in boxes

generally, we pack or place things in boxes.

we say package things in boxes, as an outer layer, so we'd say: the packaging was boxes into which cans had been packed.

packaging is generally a term for the layer closest to the product or its outermost layer but doesn't describe the distribution of those products inside the packaging.

gift packaging consisted of brightly colored boxes.

The packages of beans were packed into large boxes.


cardboard packaging
wooden crates are a type of packaging

They packed the flour bags into boxes for shipping. The packaging was cardboard.

They packed the tins in boxes but the boxes were wooden crates, an expensive packaging option.

canned into cans or tins, then pack the cans or into into boxes for shipping. The boxes are the packaging.


You pack something into something: I packed my clothes in a suitcase. If you package your clothes in a box or put your clothes in a carboard package, that is not really packing them.

I believe that in American English, 'canning' can be used to mean 'the act, process, or work of putting foods in cans or jars for preservation ', whereas in British English it is only used about putting food in cans.

@MichaelHarvey Your observation about American English is correct. When sold in stores, the jars are frequently labeled "canning jars." I suspect we're just lazy. It would be jarring to bottle something that we'd always can. :-)

@MichaelHarvey What difference does it make here? There is industrial canning in the US and there is making preserves at home. The difference is not germane here.

Can the puns, @JBH  ;-)

@TimR Now that is funny.

The verb "to can" is possible (note this is different from the modal verb "can", it has a regular third person and past tense: "he cans" "I canned"

The chopped pears are then canned.

This verb does relate to the particular type of container. You can use use other containers as verbs: "The biscuits are boxed at the factory", "The milk is bottled at the dairy".
